# Django empty field fallback

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, field

I have a model that holds user address. This model has to have `first_name` and `last_name` fields since one would like to set address to a recipient (like his company, etc.). What I'm trying to achieve is:

- If the `first_name`/`last_name` field in the address is filled - return simply that field
- If the `first_name`/`last_name` field in the address is empty - fetch the corrresponding field data from a foreignkey pointing to a proper `django.auth.models.User`
- I'd like this to be treated as normal Django field that would be present in fields lookup
- I don't want to create a method, since it's a refactoring and `Address.first_name`/`last_name` are used in various places in the application (also in model forms, etc.), so I need this to me as smooth as possible, or else, I will have to tinker around in a lot of places.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two options here. The first is to create a method to look it up dynamically, but use the `property` decorator so that other code can still use straight attribute access.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='first_name')

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name or self.user.first_name

    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, value):
       self._first_name = value
```

This will always refer to the latest value of first_name, even if the related User is changed. You can get/set the property exactly as you would an attribute: `myinstance.first_name = 'daniel'`

The other option is to override the model's `save()` method so that it does the lookup when you save:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.first_name:
        self.first_name = self.user.first_name
    # now call the default save() method
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way you don't have to change your db, but it is only refreshed on save - so if the related User object is changed but this object isn't, it will refer to the old User value.

Comment: you can specify db_column='first_name' to prevent a schema change: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Comment: so after the @first_name.setter thingy just add first_name.db_column="first_name" ? Will I be able to do: address = Address.objects.get(first_name="blah") ?

Comment: I've updated the code and explanation in response to piquadrat's comment.

Comment: Thanks for help :) it works flawlessly (the property method), only thing I'm concerned - I've got a model form and it doesn't fill empty fields with the self.user.first_name. Setting the attribute and getting is works flawlessly.

Comment: There is one more tiny problem - when doing lookups django orm can't resolve the property info field it requires the original _first_name field.

Answer (score 2):

Although this does not meet all the OP's requirements, in some use-cases where the fallback is needed in queryset filters (on the database level) it may be possible to use Django's `Coalesce()` class ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)).

The simplest solution in such a case might be queryset annotation (using the example from @daniel-roseman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1342817)):

`queryset = MyModel.objects.annotate(first_name=Coalesce('_first_name', 'user__first_name'))`

Each item obtained from the queryset will then get a `first_name` attribute, which has the value of `_first_name` with a fallback (in case the value is `null`) to `user.first_name`.

That is, assuming your model has a `user` relation.

This can be implemented e.g. in a custom manager and could also be used in conjunction with a `property` approach.

A detailed example for a similar case (override instead of fallback) is provided in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676768).