# Do properties work on Django model fields?

Tags: python, django, properties, model

I think the best way to ask this question is with some code... can I do this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):    
    foo = models.CharField(max_length = 20)    
    bar = models.CharField(max_length = 20)  

    def get_foo(self):  
        if self.bar:  
            return self.bar  
        else:  
            return self.foo  

    def set_foo(self, input):  
        self.foo = input  

    foo = property(get_foo, set_foo)
```

or do I have to do it like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _foo = models.CharField(max_length = 20, db_column='foo')
    bar = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def get_foo(self):
        if self.bar:
            return self.bar
        else:
            return self._foo

    def set_foo(self, input):
        self._foo = input

    foo = property(get_foo, set_foo)
```

**note**: you can keep the column name as 'foo' in the database by passing a db_column to the model field. This is very helpful when you are working on an existing system and you don't want to have to do db migrations for no reason

Comment: I think this is a good question but you should post your 'answer' as an actual answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question.

Comment: If I rename the field but keep the column name with `db_column`, it still wants to generate a migration to remove the field and add a new one when I run `makemigrations`. I can delete this migration, but it will always keep re-appearing whenever I run `makemigrations` in the future. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: In essence, this is a duplicate of [Django empty field fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342679).

Comment: The [filter by property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1205375) question is also similar, although a bit more generic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A model field is already property, so I would say you have to do it the second way to avoid a name clash.

When you define `foo = property(..)` it actually overrides the `foo = models..` line, so that field will no longer be accessible.

You will need to use a different name for the property and the field. In fact, if you do it the way you have it in example #1 you will get an infinite loop when you try and access the property as it now tries to return itself.

EDIT: Perhaps you should also consider not using `_foo` as a field name, but rather `foo`, and then define another name for your property because properties cannot be used in `QuerySet`, so you'll need to use the actual field names when you do a filter for example.

Comment: regarding the edit, that is good advice - I am maintaining an existing system and because the name of the field must be changed (or of the property) we abandoned this approach. The technique might turn out to be useful in the future though :)

Comment: wasn't sure if it would be accessible via closure or something like that - admittedly, I do not know much about closures

Comment: I have provided the case for '__foo' below. Using foo as a Field and another_foo as wrapping property will expose foo for direct manipulation. Although a developer in python as well as in X language should know what he is doing - there is a reason hidden variables are accepted to be a part of the language.

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned, a correct alternative to implementing your own `django.db.models.Field` class, one should use the `db_column` argument and a custom (or hidden) class attribute. I am just rewriting the code in the edit by @Jiaaro following more strict conventions for OOP in python (e.g. if `_foo` should be actually hidden):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    __foo = models.CharField(max_length = 20, db_column='foo')
    bar = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        if self.bar:
            return self.bar
        else:
            return self.__foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self.__foo = value
```

`__foo` will be resolved into `_MyModel__foo` (as seen by `dir(..)`) thus hidden ([private](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)). Note that this form also permits using of [@property decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) which would be ultimately a nicer way to write readable code.

Again, django will create `_MyModel` table with two fields `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: this is odd, but in my case, django 1.4.5 on postgres I'm getting a column foo in this case... I haven't used setter and getter and the property is read-only

Comment: Could you post the code? I am confused. In my understanding properties mechanism is provided by decorator "@property", but if you have not used it then what you call "read-only property" must be an object field *.foo* (attribute in python). Can you or can you not actually assign anything to "my_model.foo = 'baz' ??

Comment: How would you access foo? `MyMode.objects.order_by('__foo')`?

Comment: @agconti database query methods like order_by(), filter(), and get() won't work with method properties because they don't directly map to database table columns. It is their strength and weakness.

Comment: Just a note:--> Django 2.0 gives an error:  fields.E002) Field names must not contain "__"'

Comment: @sajjjan-kumar: Make that Django>=1.9. `_foo` (single underscore) *is* allowed though.

Answer (score 10):

The previous solutions suffer because @property causes problems in admin, and .filter(_foo).

A better solution would be to override **setattr** except that this can cause problems initializing the ORM object from the DB.  However, there is a trick to get around this, and it's universal.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, val):
        setter_func = 'setter_' + attrname
        if attrname in self.__dict__ and callable(getattr(self, setter_func, None)):
            super(MyModel, self).__setattr__(attrname, getattr(self, setter_func)(val))
        else:
            super(MyModel, self).__setattr__(attrname, val)

    def setter_foo(self, val):
        return val.upper()
```

The secret is '**attrname in self.__dict__**'.  When the model initializes either from new or hydrated from the **__dict__**!

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether your `property` is a means-to-an-end or an end in itself.

If you want this kind of "override" (or "fallback") behavior when filtering querysets (without first having to evaluate them), I don't think properties can do the trick. [As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1205389), Python properties do not work at the database level, so they cannot be used in queryset filters. Note that you *can* use `_foo` in the filter (instead of `foo`), as it represents an actual table column, but then the override logic from your `get_foo()` won't apply.

However, if your use-case allows it, the `Coalesce()` class from `django.db.models.functions` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)) might help.

> `Coalesce()` ... Accepts a list of at least two field names or
>   expressions and returns the first non-null value (note that an empty
>   string is not considered a null value). ...

This implies that you can specify `bar` as an override for `foo` using `Coalesce('bar','foo')`. This returns `bar`, unless `bar` is `null`, in which case it returns `foo`. Same as your `get_foo()` (except it doesn't work for empty strings), but *on the database level.*

The question that remains is how to implement this.

If you don't use it in a lot of places, simply [annotating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset may be easiest. Using your example, without the property stuff:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Then make your query like this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

queryset = MyModel.objects.annotate(bar_otherwise_foo=Coalesce('bar', 'foo'))
```

Now the items in your queryset have the magic attribute `bar_otherwise_foo`, which can be filtered on, e.g. `queryset.filter(bar_otherwise_foo='what I want')`, or it can be used directly on an instance, e.g. `print(queryset.all()[0].bar_otherwise_foo)`

The resulting [SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748307) from `queryset.query` shows that `Coalesce()` indeed works at the database level:

```
SELECT "myapp_mymodel"."id", "myapp_mymodel"."foo", "myapp_mymodel"."bar",
    COALESCE("myapp_mymodel"."bar", "myapp_mymodel"."foo") AS "bar_otherwise_foo" 
FROM "myapp_mymodel"
```

Note: you could also call your model field `_foo` then `foo=Coalesce('bar', '_foo')`, etc. It would be tempting to use `foo=Coalesce('bar', 'foo')`, but that raises a `ValueError: The annotation 'foo' conflicts with a field on the model.`

There must be several ways to create a DRY implementation, for example writing a [custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-lookups/#custom-lookups), or a [custom(ized) Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

A custom manager is easily implemented as follows (see [example in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset)):

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    """ standard manager with customized initial queryset """
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(
            bar_otherwise_foo=Coalesce('bar', 'foo'))


class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyModelManager()
    foo = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Now every queryset for `MyModel` will automatically have the `bar_otherwise_foo` annotation, which can be used as described above.

Note, however, that e.g. updating `bar` on an instance will not update the annotation, because that was made on the queryset. The queryset will need to be re-evaluated first, e.g. by getting the updated instance from the queryset.

Perhaps a combination of a custom manager with annotation and a Python `property` could be used to get the best of both worlds ([example at CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/209421)).