# Inline with M2M using through

Tags: django, django-admin

Given three models related by M2M fields:

> A <-> B <-> C

**models**

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = ManyToManyField(A)

class C(models.Model):
    b = ManyToManyField(B)
```

With the following admin I have an Inline between A-B:

**admin**

```
class BInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = B.a.through

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BInline,]
```

What I need now is to have another inline between A and C. But I don't know how to set the relation among them.

```
class CInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = #¿?

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ BInline,
                CInline,
                ]
```

Comment: Why do you want to display all the C's in A, wouldn't it make more sense to display them as an inline in B?

Comment: @Written I would agree with you but this time it has to be like this for the purposes of the application.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well I recommend checking out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999577/django-orm-way-of-going-through-multiple-many-to-many-relationship if you haven't already. Might be along the lines of what you're looking for