# Printing Django QuerySet SQL with ""

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

You can print a queryset's SQL as follows:

```
print str(queryset.query)
```

however, for some reason this removes quotation marks, so you get:

```
SELECT `tableA`.`fieldA` FROM `fieldA` WHERE `tableA`.`fieldB` = Foo
```

instead of:

```
SELECT `tableA`.`fieldA` FROM `fieldA` WHERE `tableA`.`fieldB` = "Foo"
```

notice the missing `""`

How can this be corrected?

Comment: The database backends pass the query template and parameters separately to your database — Django itself _never_ needs to build a correctly quoted query with populated placeholders. This is why you only get this incomplete solution for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 20):

If the underlying database is **PostgreSQL** you can do:

```
from django.db import connection
sql, params = queryset.query.sql_with_params()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.mogrify(sql, params)
```

`sql_with_params` returns the plain query without any values substituted and the parameters that will be inserted in the query.

It is still **not** recommended to use `.mogrify()` for other purposes than debugging because the method may disappear in the future.

If you want to execute the query, you can/should just use `.raw()`.

```
YourModel.objects.raw(sql, params)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I starting to dig into this, becuase I was thinking that it was possible to get the proper SQL statement :D, working like a charm with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

not quite what you want, but if you have `DEBUG = True` you can use

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

update:

looking at the `Queryset` `__str__` method:

```
__str__(self)
|      Returns the query as a string of SQL with the parameter values
|      substituted in.
|      
|      Parameter values won't necessarily be quoted correctly, since that is
|      done by the database interface at execution time.
```

Comment: That works only after the query has been sent whereas I need it printed before in case something goes wrong with the fetch

Answer (score 2):

If this is for debug purpose you should look into django-debug-toolbar that will show you all queries ran for any view you're looking at