# Django's str(queryset.query) returns invalid SQL if I compare datetimes

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a Django queryset that I prepare with `queryset.filter(date__gte=datetime(2011,1,1))`

If I then call `str(queryset.query)` I see this in the string:

```
... WHERE "App_table"."date" >= 2011-1-1
```

However, this is invalid SQL code as if I run this in Postgresql I get this error:

```
... WHERE "App_table"."date" >= 2011-1-1
ERROR:  operator does not exist: date >= integer
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Why is this happening and how can I ask Django to output proper SQL code that I can work on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `query. sql_with_params()` method.

```
print(q.query. sql_with_params())
```

This will print a parameterized version of the query.

Comment: This returns a tuple where `[0]` is the query with `%s` in the place of parameters, and [1] are the parameters. If I do `queryTuple[0] % queryTuple[1]` it gives me the same invalid string as `str(q.query)`. So I guess I should use `sql_with_params`, manually search for datetimes in [1] and convert them to strings surrounded by quotes. No way for Django to do that?

Comment: Here's a possible answer to my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828674/1307020

Comment: Yes the point is that this is now the responsibility of the db adapter rather than Django.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Danel Roseman's answer, how I got the valid SQL statement is using this:

```
sql, params = unioned_qs.query.sql_with_params()

params_with_quotes = []
for x in params:
   params_with_quotes.append("'%s'" % x)
print(sql % tuple(params_with_quotes))
```

What makes the Django SQL query invalid is because of missing quotes and by replacing all the values with a quoted string, the SQL should be valid. Works in one of my edge cases but haven't tested this theory widely enough.

Tested on Django 3.2 and Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Django Debug Toolbar generates correct SQL string with quoted parameters.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I filter out dates if my model field is `models.DateField`:

```
  queryset.filter(date__gte=datetime.date(2011,1,1))
```

I guess that if you have declared the field `date` as `DateTimeField`, the comparison would work.

Comment: Take `str(queryset.query)`, and copypaste it into your database. It won't work, regardless of wether the column is there or not.

Comment: In the expression "WHERE "App_table"."date" >= 2011-1-1" Postgres interposes the operand 2011-1-1 as "integer-integer-integer" evaluating in this case to the integer 2009. So the statement effectively becomes "date >= integer", and that is an invalid comparison.  If you an expression to be a date you must tell Postgres that's what you want. Try WHERE "App_table"."date" >= '2011-1-1'::date.