# preferred way to filter data models.objects.all().exclude() or models.objects.filter()

Tags: python, django

I'm just curious. What is the correct way or should I say, the efficient way in filtering data? I'm still learning. Say you have thousands of records then you want to retrieve all active records.

Should it be done like this.

```
Records.objects.all().exclude(active=False)
```

Or

```
Records.objects.filter(active=True)
```

Do they have a difference or just the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two expressions produce different queries.

You always can inspect them by looking at the `query` attribute of a queryset:

```
>>> print Records.objects.all().exclude(active=False).query
```

`Records.objects.all().exclude(active=False)` produces:

```
SELECT 
    <list_of_fields> 
FROM 
    `<table_name>` 
WHERE 
    NOT (`<table_name>`.`active` = False)
```

`Records.objects.filter(active=True)` produces:

```
SELECT 
    <list_of_fields> 
FROM 
    `<table_name>` 
WHERE 
    `<table_name>`.`active` = True
```

See also:

- [Getting the SQL from a Django QuerySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748295/getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset)

Comment: Between the two, which do you prefer?

Comment: @BoyPasmo for me, making `filter(active=True)` is more explicit and clear.

Comment: @BoyPasmo plus, it produces a bit more straightforward query, no inversions. In terms of speed, I think database "engines" like mysql are smart enough to optimize both of them and run in a same way.

Comment: @BoyPasmo you can also take a look at the `EXPLAIN` plan and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @BoyPasmo in case of mysql, take a [look](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).