# Filter by a specific date in Django (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: python, django, date

In Django I have a 1 input form that is created like this:

```
class ListTripsForm(forms.Form):
    date_to_edit = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y'],
                                   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                        'class': 'form-control',
                                        'id': 'trips_month'}),
                                   initial=date.strftime(date.today(),
                                                         '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

The user selects a date (eg. 5/26/2017).

In the DB I have a datetime column.

Trying to get all the 'trips' from that day.

I've tried a few different ways and none have lead to success.

I am trying to add a filter to select just results from that day:

```
date = request.POST.get('date_to_edit', '')  # users submitted date mm/dd/yyyy
user_trips_for_date = Trip.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, trip_date=datetime.date(date))
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range could be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you'll have an easier time of things if you instantiate your form as normal and access the field rather than extracting it directly from `request.POST`. Part of the point of the form classes is to handle type conversions.

Once you have that, if `trip_date` is a DateTimeField:

```
form = ListTripsForm(request.POST)
user_trips_for_date = Trip.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, trip_date__date=form.cleaned_data['date_to_edit'])
```

Plus the usual validation code of course, the point is to a) use the form to get a `datetime.date` instance and then b) use a `__date` filter clause.

Comment: I think you mean `form.cleaned_data['date_to_edit']`.

Comment: Hey, that worked great! it doesn't pull up the appropriate responses from the DB however. Would that be because it doesn't include the time portion? For example: this input is a DateField, so I think by default it's assigned 00:00:00:0000 for the time.  The items recorded in the DB actually have hours/minutes assigned to them - so they don't match up when filtered. Does that seem accurate?

Comment: The `__date` part is supposed to tell the database that the query should match on year/month/date only and not worry about the time: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#date What you're describing is what I'd expect to see if your filter clause were `trip_date=form.cleaned_data...`

Comment: Alright. I'll keep playing around - this was ultimately very helpful and the right answer. I think it's just something else going on that I haven't identified yet (which will probably have me saying, "duh").  Thanks again!

Comment: Odd. If I make it `trip_date=form.cleaned_data['date_to_edit']` it will find the one I entered with 00:00:00000 timestamp. If I set it to `trip_date__gt=form.cleaned_data['date_to_edit']` then it finds one of the other trips I put in that wasn't set to 00:00:0000. But if I set it to `trip_date__date=form.cleaned_data['date_to_edit']` it doesn't find anything. Strange.

Comment: Yeah, sounds odd. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django has some answers for older versions of Django that you might be able to adapt, but personally I'd probably set up a debugger and look at exactly what the objects are - confirm that `cleaned_data['date_to_edit']` is a `datetime.date` instance, then check the SQL as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748295/getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset