# Django queryset filter extremely slow, how to improve speed

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've been trying to optimize this Django query set search the last two days and have been unable to speed it up. My backend is MYSQL.

There are three tables: Book, Bookstore and Category. Book has 1 million observations, Bookstore has 500 observations and category has 10k observations

```
table = Book.objects.filter(Category=pk, bookstore__in=bookstore_objects).order_by('title').prefetch_related(Prefetch('bookstore', to_attr='bookstore_list'))[:50]
```

The first time this query is run-in the shell it takes 20+ seconds and subsequently it takes about 3-5 seconds. Please help me speed up this query. I cannot understand why it's so slow.

Comment: You're missing index.

Paste the above code in django-shell and get the SQL query output by appending `.query` to it as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748295/getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset

Next, paste the above query in MYSQL shell prefixed with `EXPLAIN`.

Mysql will tell whether it's using indexes or not.

Comment: Would this be an index problem if it's only slow the first time and then subsequently pretty fast. The first time I run this query it takes 20+ seconds and after only 3-5 seconds. If it's an index issue, I thought that it would be the same speed every time,. But I could be wrong.

Comment: MySQL tends to cache a query's result after 1st execution. I am not exactly sure how the cache invalidates, but IIRC on any write to the table MySQL would invalidate the cache.