# Django filter has_key generates wrong SQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to filter some objects that have no specific value in the field. I tried to do it like this:

```py
MyModel.objects\
    .filter(<some filters>)\
    .exclude(json_field__has_key='some_field', json_field__some_field=True)
```

But this code generates wrong SQL query:

```sql
... 
AND NOT (
    "my_model"."json_field" ? some_field AND
    ("my_model"."json_field" -> 'some_field') = 'true' AND
    "my_model"."json_field" IS NOT NULL)
)
...
```

On the first line `some_field` used without qoutes. I fixed it by adding single qoutes to the string like this: `json_field__has_key="'some_field'"` but I dont think it's a good solution.

Does anyone have an idea why it works this way and how I should fix it?

Comment: It's probably worth raising a ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my bad...
I just logged my queries as `queryset.query` that has really wrong representation of the SQL query. When I logged real queries using connector I saw correct query (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748308/8336601) for more details).