# How to convert Django model into DDL statement

Tags: python, django

I created a python code to create CLI tools that visualize the database schema.
But I have an issue.
I have tried to read the models.py in the django project and get sql statement but I don't know how to do it.

I want to convert django model into sql query.

Comment: is this [getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748295/getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset) you are looking for ?

Comment: I just want to get query for creating the table, not selecting an object from database. And what I want to do is to get sql query for creating the table from the django model. I know how to get query in django project but this python app uses models.py file.