# Simultaneously making calculation on two fields in django, but only one is being performed at a time

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to perform the both operations at the same time but only one is getting returned at a time. If I remove either of them, the other one get performed. Is there any way round to get both of them working at the same time? I'm talking about grossannualsalary and textDeduct.

```
class Salarie(models.Model):

    grossmonthlysalary = models.FloatField(
        _('Monthly Salary'),
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        default=0.00
    )

    monthlyincometax = models.FloatField(
        _('Monthly Income Tax'),
        null=False,
        blank=False
    )

    contractperiod = models.IntegerField(
        _('Contract Period'),
        null=False,
        blank=False
    )

    grossannualsalary = models.FloatField(
        _('Gross Annual Salary'),
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    taxDeduct = models.FloatField(
        _('Tax Deduction'),
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        default=0.00
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.grossannualsalary = self.grossmonthlysalary * self.contractperiod
        super(Salarie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.taxDeduct = self.grossmonthlysalary * self.monthlyincometax / 100
        super(Salarie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why is `grossannualsalary` a field if it is always the result of a calculation? why not just make it a property? The same goes for `taxDeduct`

Comment: And why have you defined the save method twice? You can only have one method for a name. Why not put them both in the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand why you write two save method in one model. Please try this.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.grossannualsalary = self.grossmonthlysalary * self.contractperiod
    self.taxDeduct = self.grossmonthlysalary * self.monthlyincometax / 100
    super(Salarie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This still only does a calculation "one at a time", its not exactly clear (to me) what the op is actually trying to do

Comment: I agree that if grossannualsalary and taxDeduct are derived from calcuation of other model field than it's better to write property.

Comment: @Darshit would love to use property in this situation, could you please assist me transform this code to a property calculation.

Comment: @IsraelZ.Kollie please go through [this](https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-replace-django-model-field-property/) tutorial and [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454727/do-properties-work-on-django-model-fields)